# How can I load an inline script after the enqueued scripts in admin?

Tags: admin, wp-enqueue-script, scripts

I am having a heck of a time finding an answer to this solution. I have googled everything I can think of but I can't find anything. I want to load an inline JavaScript tag in the footer of the admin. When I use the admin_footer action, the code is added *before* the JS tags that are called by the wp_enqueue_script function. I need this script to be called *after* those scripts. How can I achieve this?

This is what I am using now:

```
<?php add_action('admin_footer', 'gallery_js', PHP_INT_MAX);

function gallery_js(){ ?>
<script>
(function($){
    $('#deleteSelected').serviceGallery({
        ajaxUrl: '<?php echo JZS_PLUGIN_PATH.'/admin/partials/service-gallery-ajax.php';?>'
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
    <?php }
```

See this image for a better explanation:
[image]
The image is when using the admin_footer action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the answer. I need to use the [admin_print_footer_scripts](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2016/07/15/introducing-admin_print_footer_scripts-hook_suffix-in-4-6/) action. This will add scripts after the scripts that were called with `wp_enqueue_scripts`.

Comment: ah that hook is new to me, thanks for sharing. (set your answer as accepted)

Answer (score 0):

I did the following test:

```
add_action('admin_footer', 'admin_footer_test', PHP_INT_MAX);
function admin_footer_test() {
    ?>
    <!--
    ADMIN_FOOTER
    -->
    <?php
}

add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'admin_enqueue_scripts_test', PHP_INT_MAX);
function admin_enqueue_scripts_test() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'sq_general_js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/test.js', array('jquery'), '', true  );
}

add_action( 'admin_print_scripts', 'admin_print_scripts_test', PHP_INT_MAX );
function admin_print_scripts_test() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'projects_portrait_slider', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/test.js', array('jquery'), '', true  );
}
```

`admin_footer` is always above the script enqueue's. With `admin_print_scripts` you can get below `admin_enqueue_scripts`.

Regards, Bjorn

Comment: I am not enqueing a JS file. I am enqueing a JS tag.

Comment: srry did not see the PHP and admin_footer. i'll do some testing, one sec